How to solve $x^k=a?$
I do not understand how to solve equations of the form $x^k=a$ for $k \in \mathbb{K}$ and $a \in U_n$. I did try to write down everything I do understand and how I would have (tried) to do it. But first some context.
Let $U_n$ be the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
I know $U_n=\{a+n \mathbb{Z}:gcd(a,n)=1\}$. Let $log_\xi :U_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\phi(n)\mathbb{Z}$ be the logarithm of $\xi$.
I recently learned the following:
Consider the following equation in the cyclic $U_n$
$x^k=a$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in U_n$.

Let $\xi$ be a primitive root modulo $n$ and $\alpha:=\log_\xi a$, i.e.
$a \equiv \xi^{\alpha} mod n$. Applying the logarithm yields the
equivalent equation: $k \log_{\xi}x=\log_{\xi}x^k=\log_{\xi}a=\alpha$ in
$\mathbb{Z}/\phi(n) \mathbb{Z}$ (where $\phi$ is the euler-function).
The equation $k \log_\xi x=\alpha$ can be solved by the methods we
learned to solve congruence equations. Applying $exp_\xi$ to all those
solution we get all solutions of $x^k=a$.

Why do we need to solve $k \log_\xi x=\alpha$ by the methods we know for congruence equations? Can't I just look up the value of $\log_\xi x$ and then divide by $k$? I do not see how we got a congruence equation of a sudden.
After that there was an example:

Example: We will solve the equation $x^3=\overline{11}$ in
$\mathbb{F}_{19}$. We chose $\xi=2$ as prime root modulo $19$. To find
$\log_2 \overline{11}$ be consider a table of the values of $\exp_2$. (I
am not going to write down the whole table, but just the important
entry) $\exp_2 \overline{12}=\overline{11}$, thus we see that $\log_2
 \overline{11}=\overline{12}$.

This is how far I could follow the example. From here on I do not know what happens.
Continuation of the example:

Since $gcd(3,18)|12$ the equation $3y \equiv 12$ mod $18$ has
solutions $y \equiv 4$ mod $6$. Modulo $18$ $y$ is equal to $4,10$ or
$16$. Thus the equation $x^3 =\overline{11}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{19}$ has
the solutions
$\exp_2\overline{4}=\overline{16},\exp_2\overline{10}=\overline{17} and
> \exp_2\overline{16}=\overline{5}$.

Here again it seems that the methods used are ones known from congruence equations. I still don't know why we need to solve a congruence equation (and which one).
How I would try to approach this problem:
Would it be me, I would do the first part of the example as is.
When I know that $\log_2\overline{11}=\overline{12}$  would  try to "insert" $\log_2 \overline{11}=\overline{12}$ into the equation $3 \cdot \log_2 x=\overline{12}$. But I can't think of how to exactly. I can see that I somehow need to incorporate congruance equations, but do not know how.

First, we should take a look at the $\log_\xi$ -function.
Let $\xi$ be a primitive root modulo $n$, then
$\log_{\xi}: U_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}$ . The equation  $x^k=a$  is an equation in  $U_n$. By applying  $\log_{\xi}$  to it, you are "transporting" the equation into $\mathbb{Z}/\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}$, where the new equation loos as follows: $k \cdot \log_{\xi}x=\log_{\xi}a$.
In your case, we have $k=3$, $\xi=2$,$n=19$, $\varphi(19)=18$ and $a=\overline{11}$.
Thus we need to solve the equation
$3 \log_{2}x=\log_{2} \overline{11}  $. Then considering the values of $\exp_2$, we can determine that $\log_2\overline{11}=\overline{12}$. Note that $\overline{12}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/ 18 \mathbb{Z}$.
Thus, we have to solve $3 \log_2 x=\overline{12}$ (in $\mathbb{Z}/ 18 \mathbb{Z}$).
Define $y:=\log_2 x$ to get $3 y = \overline{12} $ (in $\mathbb{Z}/ 18 \mathbb{Z}$).
We can write the equation $3 y = \overline{12} $ also as $3y \equiv 12 \mod 18$.
